# jQuery DataTable Child row with data from SQL asp net server side

Tags: jquery, asp.net, datatables, webforms, asprepeater

I'm been using jquery datatables with asp net repeater often and avoid the dull look of gridview and now I wanted to try adding child row with a listview but I don't know how to do it 'cause every example is using jquery and ajax. This is just an example with static text to bind the table for now and test

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptArtigos" runat="server">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <table id="tblArtigos" class="table table-bordered dataTable">
            <thead class="thead-dark">
                <tr>
                    <th style="width: 20px;">ID</th>
                    <th style="width: 120px">Ref. Cliente</th>
                    <th style="width: 100px">Ref. Interna</th>
                    <th style="width: 100px">Nome</th>
                    <th style="width: 100px">Logística</th>
                    <th style="width: 100px">Estado</th>
                    <th style="width: 10px;">Editar</th>
                    <th style="width: 10px;">Validar</th>
                    <th style="width: 10px;">Rejeitar</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>REF12345</td>
                    <td>123456</td>
                    <td>User</td>
                    <td>Não Validado</td>
                    <td>Criado</td>
                    <td class="text-center">
                        <asp:ImageButton ImageUrl="/Images/Buttons/edit.png" CssClass="" Width="25" runat="server" />
                    </td>
                    <td class="text-center">
                        <asp:ImageButton ImageUrl="/Images/Buttons/success.png" CssClass="" Width="25" runat="server" />
                    </td>
                    <td class="text-center">
                        <asp:ImageButton ImageUrl="/Images/Buttons/x-button.png" CssClass="" Width="25" runat="server" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <FooterTemplate>
            </table>
        </FooterTemplate>
   </asp:Repeater>
```

I'm not sure where to start from here. I think i should add another column and code the listview inside it. The problem is making the button to show the listview